# How to get / change value of HTML5 progress bar?

Tags: javascript, css, html

Below is the html and js I have for my progress bar:
But my console is telling me the value of the variable `dragonHealth` is `null` when it should be 100 as initialized. From what I have found, the value should be a floating point variable so why is it coming out as `null`? Not too familiar with this `progress` tag btw. Thanks for the help. Btw, the health ID in my css is just a blank one created just to reference it in js.

JS

```
var dragonHealth = document.getElementById("health").value;
```

html

```
<progress id="health" value="100" max="100"></progress>
```

Comment: works fine here https://fiddle.jshell.net/umbkuzyj/ . (check the console)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make sure the JS is run after the DOM is ready (*or at the end of the page*)

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  /* DOM is ready, so we can query for its elements */
  var dragonHealth = document.getElementById("health").value;
  console.log(dragonHealth);
  
  /*additional code for comment*/
  document.querySelector('button').addEventListener("click", function(event){
    document.getElementById("health").value += 5;
  });
})
```

```html
<progress id="health" value="60" max="100"></progress>
<button>change progress value</button>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, that worked. On a side note, the progress bar visual itself does not update to reflect value changes in my fight simulation yet I know the values are changing from an if statement I have later on. I thought it was a async issue but it doesn't update at the end of the simulation either. Do you know what could be the problem here?

Comment: @avisaxena33 make sure you are updating the element value and not just the variable you store the progress. (*updated answer with example*).

Comment: Yeah I did that, I'm changing the value of dragonHealth, but then I also have a line of code that sets the value of the progress bar to dragonHealth as well but the bar still doesn't change, it's simply static

Comment: can you post a live demo with the problem ?

Comment: I can't really post a live demo because of all the css and html thats linked with pictures and stuff so the whole program won't work, but here's the function that's having a problem.

https://jsfiddle.net/jezhL835/#&togetherjs=MlS2zaKQby

Comment: Bascially what I've done now is, instead of setting drag health to the progress value which is initially 100, i just set the value of the var to 100 straight up and then after every time the draghealth value is changed through the function, I set the value of the actual progress element to the new dragHealth value. Not sure why this isn't updating the bar itself though.

Comment: the fiddle works fine if you create a global `dragonHealth` with an initial value and call the function.