# How can I grab a value from a PHP generated div and use Javascript to then change the width of a progress bar HTML5 element?

Tags: javascript, php, html, processwire

What I'm trying to do is add progress bars to several cards I have on a website. I'm using Processwire CMS (which utilizes PHP) to generate my cards and each card has a progress element, a raised amount, and a goal amount like so:

```
<progress class="progressBar" id="progressbar<?php echo $currentSection; ?>" value="0" max="100"></progress>

<span id="raisedNum<?php echo $count; ?>" class="hidden">
    <?php echo $raised; ?>
</span>

<span id="goalNum<?php echo $count; ?>" class="hidden">
    <?php echo $goal; ?>
</span>
```

These elements are all wrapped in a loop that generates my cards. I am then trying to grab the values in the id="raisedNum" and "goalNum" spans using Javascript, divide the goal amount by the raised amount, and then insert that number back into the Progress "value" attribute.

Here is the Javascript code I have thus far, that doesn't work:

```
do {
var count = 0;
var raised = document.getElementById("raisedNum".count);
var goal = document.getElementById("goalNum".count);

raised2 = parseInt(raised);
goal2 = parseInt(goal);
var percent = goal2 / raised2;

document.getElementById("progressbar".count).value += percent;

count++; } while (raised != null);
```

I'm *very* new to Javascript and would really appreciate any help to figure this out.

Also, I used a defer attribute on my Javascript import tag but am not sure if I should or not. I imagine that I need the script to run after all of the cards have been loaded so that it can grab the values; however, it still needs to change those values after it does the math and generates the percentage values.

I've looked at similar StackOverflow questions like this:
[How to get / change value of HTML5 progress bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43524985/how-to-get-change-value-of-html5-progress-bar)
but couldn't figure out how to change it to meet my needs.

Thanks in advance for any helpful replies!

Comment: Why not do the calculation in PHP and output the value with the rest of the HTML? `<progress class="progressBar" id="progressbar<?php echo $currentSection; ?>" value="<?php echo $raised / $goal * 100; ?>" max="100"></progress>` No need for JS, right?

Comment: I originally tried to do everything in PHP, which I agree would be the ideal method. The problem I'm currently experiencing is that PHP sees $raised and $goal as strings no matter what I do. In Processwire I use this code `$raised = $page->get("raisedAmount$count");` to get the value of raised but when I try to typecast it to an integer, it says that number is 0, regardless of what's actually stored in the raisedAmount$count value. I have 40,000 stored in one of the fields but after typecasting them integers it changes it to 0 instead of 40000. I echoed the value which confirmed this.

Comment: `echo` won't tell you the data type. What happens when you `var_dump($raised)` and `var_dump($goal)`?

Comment: For some crazy reason, the parseInt function wasn't working to typecast the strings to integers so that I could use them to get the percentage. After figuring out I could change them in the CMS to integers, I was easily able to calculate it and use it in my progress element's value field. Problem solved, thanks for the responses though!

Answer (score 0):

You used the **.** operator from PHP to concat two variables.
In JavaScript, you need to use the **+** operator:
`var raised = document.getElementById("raisedNum" + count);`

If you put a period after any object in JavaScript, it will try to get that property of it. **"raisedNum".count** would give the **count** property of the string, but that doesn't exist, so JavaScript wants to get an element by an undefined id, but there's no element with undefined id. Then, you call **.value**, but it will throw an error because you can't read the value of **null**.

Comment: Yeah, like I said I'm a noob with JS. I tried changing the code to use the + operator instead of a . but it's still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured out how to do this entirely using PHP. I was initially having trouble typecasting the strings to integers but after realizing that I could change the field types to integers, didn't need to do any typecasting and was able to quickly create a formula that gave me the percentage from value/raised and insert it into the value attribute of my Progress tag. Thanks you all for all of the responses though!